# I want to pass a list of SqlParameter to a function which executes stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, lis

I want to save two values say `@name` and `@pwd` to a table, for this I can use following code in aspx page.

```
public void save1()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TEST",con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", txtUname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", txtPwd.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

But I want to pass these two variable as a single `List<SqlParameter>` variable as

```
List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>();
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", uname));
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@pwd", pwd));
```

Thus the declaration of above function changes from

```
public void save1()
```

to

```
public void save1(List<SqlParameter> param)
```

But my problem is I don't know how to extract those two variables from this `param` and then add them to the `cmd` variable. I need your help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [`SqlParameterCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection)

Comment: look up `foreach` loops.

Comment: It's hard to believe you don't even know how to loop.

Comment: You can also use `AddRange()`

Comment: Don't know why this question gets downvoted, it's trivial, but everyone did it at their begins...

Comment: Yes It worked when I used,

Comment: foreach(var p in param)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }

Comment: @Oscar because someone able to use `usings`, not use sql code prone to SqlInjection should be able to foreach, AddRange. So code is probably not really written by Richu and some "basic" coding tutorials are needed?

Comment: @Crowcoder bro i was confused with how to use the loop properly

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { }` - don't do this. You want to know if there's an exception.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you loop or use AddRange(). They will both basically run the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Have your Save function look like so:

```
public void Save1(List<SqlParameter> param)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TEST", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (var item in param)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Then have param be accessible to the calling routine as well as the Save1(..) function, like so:

```
public/*private*/ List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>();
```

Lastly, your calling routine will call Save1(..) as following:

```
string uname = "...";
string pwd = "...";
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", uname));
param.Add(new SqlParameter("@pwd", pwd));
Save1(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's only going to be two parameters you could use this

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param[1]);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Not for just two variable @Mohamed, Finally I made it by using ` foreach(var p in param)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }`

Comment: Yes that'll work fine as well. If a post answers your question, pls mark it as answer. If more than one post help, please upvoted them as this helps StackOverflow get better.

Answer (score 0):

See below code

```
List<SqlParameter> Parameters = new List<SqlParameter>(){
    new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "@yourparamname", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value= ""}
    ,..
};

public void ExecuteSQL(string SP, List<SqlParameter> Parameters){
    SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");SqlCommand CM = new SqlCommand(SP, CN);CM.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    CM.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters.ToArray());CM.ExecuteNonQuery();CM.Conection.Dispose();           
}

ExecuteSQL("dbo.[SP_Name]", Parameters);
```

The key is: `CM.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters.ToArray());`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for loop to access each individual parameter inside the list.

for(interesting i=0, i< parameter.Count, i++){
   // 
    var param1 = param[i];
}